# How do I change the aspect ratio of the camera in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, camera, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

First of all, my app is written using mostly in Xamarin Forms, but uses a CustomRenderer for the camera. Not sure if that will affect anything.

My problem currently is that I need to change the aspect ratio of the camera from 16:9 to something custom, if this is even possible.

I have tried changing the width and height independently, but, for example, if I were to change the height to something significantly higher, all it does is expand the width and height at the same rate until it 'hits the side of the box' that the camera is contained in, so it results in the width being correct, but the height I specified in code is a lot higher than the actual height of the camera.

```
var videoPreviewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(captureSession)
{
    // 16 / 9 = 1.77777778
    Frame = new CGRect(-15, -45, size, size * 1.77777778) /*LiveCameraStream.Bounds*/,
    BackgroundColor = new CGColor(0, 255, 0) //Green
};
viewLayer.AddSublayer(videoPreviewLayer);
viewLayer.Bounds = new CGRect(4, -50, 100, 50);
viewLayer.BackgroundColor = new CGColor(255, 0, 0); //Red
//Background colours included just for dev purposes to distinguish between layers
```

Whenever I set the height to be width * 1.777... it results in a perfect 16:9 aspect ratio, which unfortunately is not what I need. The image below shows how it is currently looking, with ideally the camera taking up all of the red area.

[image: app screenshot]

So my question, is how do I change the aspect ratio of this camera, if it is even possible?